# Entity Framework Composite Keys Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've got 2 tables in my database:

Game:

```
public class Game
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [ForeignKey("WinningSlot"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int numer { get; set; }
    public string md5 { get; set; }
    public string secret { get; set; }
    public GameStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int SlotsNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ForceEndTime { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("WinningSlot"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int WinningSlotId { get; set; 
    public GameSlot WinningSlot { get; set; }
    public double SlotPrice { get; set; }
    public List<GameSlot> Slots { get; set; }
}
```

GameSlot:

```
public class GameSlot
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key]
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GameId")]
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1), Key]
    public int Slot { get; set; }
    public int? PlayerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlayerId")]
    public WotUser Player { get; set; }
    public string SecretData { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see PK of `GameSlot` table is composite and consists of `GameID` (which is also a FK to `Game`) and `Slot` (which is slot number). Everything works fine until I am trying to add a `WinningSlot` property to my `Game` table. It generates another `Game_Id` column for it in the `GameSlot` table on database update.

All my attempts to mess with fluent api failed. Can you help me please make a normal relation for this to work? The `winningslot` column is optional and can be null. Thank you!

Update:
Problem solved with FluentApi:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
                .HasOptional(g => g.WinningSlot)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(g => new { g.Id, g.WinningSlotId });
```

But here is another:
When I am trying to add a slot like this(example code) it works fine:

```
var game = db.Games.Find(1);
game.WinningSlotId = 1;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But if I want to set the slot instead:

```
 var game = db.Games.Find(1);
 var gameslot = db.Slots.Find(game.Id, 1);
 game.WinningSlot = gameslot;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

It will throw an exception telling me That I can not modify Id property of a Game. What is wrong here if gameslot has its gameID = game.Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<GameSlot>()
  .HasKey(g => new { g.GameID, g.Slot })
  .HasRequired(g => g.Game)
  .WithMany(g => g.GameSlot);
```

EDIT: I found why it is making the index, you need to make your navigational properties virtual. Because of this you don't need the fluent api I've written above, but personally I find fluent mapping to be more clear than using Data Annotations like you did by not cluttering your models with attributes.

```
public class Game
{
public Game()
{
    Slots = new HashSet<GameSlot>();
}

[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[ForeignKey("WinningSlot"), Column(Order = 0)]
public int Id { get; set; }
public int numer { get; set; }
public string md5 { get; set; }
public string secret { get; set; }
public GameStatus Status { get; set; }
public int SlotsNumber { get; set; }
public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndDime { get; set; }
public DateTime? ForceEndTime { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("WinningSlot"), Column(Order = 1)]
public int WinningSlotId { get; set;     
public double SlotPrice { get; set; }

public virtual GameSlot WinningSlot { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<GameSlot> Slots { get; set; }
}
```

(It is more common to use interfaces together with hashset for your navigational collection properties.)

Also if you want `Game` to be accessible from `GameSlot`, either through lazy/eager loading, you will have to add a navigation property to `Game` too, but that on a sidenote.

Regarding the second error you have, `Game.Id` is both the primary key of `Game` and foreign Key to `GameSlot`. If you try to appoint another winningslot to game, you're trying to change the Id of `GameSlot` too.